# Iterate over raster images and mosaic images based on same dates using Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, imagery, iterator, image-mosaic

I am trying to mosaic images with same dates in a folder. As there are images with different dates in the folder
[image: folder containing images]

I have looped through the images with just SR_clip.tif extension using wildcard that I require but unable to figure out which logical operator to use which specifies if my images have the same dates create a mosaic or else move on to the next images with same dates and create a new mosaic.

[image: Model Builder to iterate through all images with specified wildcard]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import arcpy

# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/datasets/planetscope/2021/2021_09-2021_08_psscene_analytic_sr_udm2/copy raster udm"
location = "D:/datasets/planetscope/2021/2021_09-2021_08_psscene_analytic_sr_udm2/mosaic"

# Get and print a list of GRIDs from the workspace
#rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*Analytic*", "TIF")
#for raster in rasters:
  #  print(raster)
    
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*udm2*", "TIF")
for raster in rasters:
    print(raster)
values = set(map(lambda x:x.split('_')[-7], rasters)) #Find unique groups
values
newlist = [[y for y in rasters if y.split('_')[-7]==x] for x in values] #From the rasterlist, create a new list of 
#lists of grouped rasters
    
for group in newlist:
    if len(group)>0: #Dont mosaic single rasters
        outname='udm2_Mosaic_{0}.tif'.format(group[0].split('_')[-7])
        arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters=group, 
                                           output_location = location,raster_dataset_name_with_extension=outname, 
                                           pixel_type="8_BIT_UNSIGNED",cellsize="", number_of_bands="8", 
                                           mosaic_method="BLEND",mosaic_colormap_mode="MATCH")
```